# Spring boot Applicaation unable to map a List object in PUT API call

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am using a List of Objects in my PUT/PATCH API call which does an update for a list of objects.Below are the sample POJO and the wrapper object. To my surprise the request mapping is failing.

**POJO:**

```
public class Product{


}


public class Products{

    private List<Product> products;

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setSubscription(List<Product> products) {
        this.products= products;
    }
}
```

**Controller class:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("app")
public class ProductController {

@Autowired
private ProductService productService ;





  @RequestMapping(value = "/products", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
        public @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT) @ResponseBody void updateProducts(
                @RequestBody Products products)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, MalformedURLException {

            productService .updateProducts(products);   

       } 


     @RequestMapping(value = "/products", method = RequestMethod.PATCH, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
        public @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT) @ResponseBody void updateProducts(
                @RequestBody Products products)
            throws IllegalArgumentException, MalformedURLException {

            productService .updateProducts(products);   

       }
```

JSON Request:

```
{

      "name": "MySmartPhone",
      "brand":"Samsung"

}
```

URI for local testing through postman h**ttp://localhost:8080/app/products**

Comment: your request object is wrong. It should be a list of object. But you have it as a single object

Comment: what is your question/problem exactly ?

Comment: So , if I try to map an wrapping a list like products in the above case, wont' it consider a single object in the list if I pass a single object?

Comment: Your JOSN request should be like `{"products":[{

      "name": "MySmartPhone",
      "brand":"Samsung"

}]}  `

Comment: @SudhirOjha I have changed my request JSON.But when the mapping of JSON to Products list is failing.In the below, I am getting products as null in the requestbody.

Answer (score 1):

Your Controller has `Products`  which is List of `Product`. You need to pass same pattern in JSON.

Assuming your Product has below fields

```
public class Product{
    public String name;
    public String brand;
}
```

Your request JSON should be like this

```
{
    "products" : [
        {
            "name": "MySmartPhone",
            "brand":"Samsung"
        }       
    ]
}
```

EDIT 1:

I tried your code in POSTMAN and I am able to see mapping. Check if in Postman in body you have selected `application/json`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/products", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT) @ResponseBody void updateProducts(
            @RequestBody Products products) {
        System.out.println(products.getProducts().get(0).getName());
   } 

OUTPUT:
MySmartPhone
```

Comment: Even after updating the JSON to contain a list of products, I am seeing the binded products in the @requestbody as null.

Comment: I am able to see Object in Controller class

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON request is not correct ,Please check below code.

```
public class Product{
    public String name;
    public String brand;
    //Setter and Getter
}

public class Products{

   private List<Product> products;

   public List<Product> getProducts() {
     return products;
   }

   public void setSubscription(List<Product> products) {
     this.products= products;
   }
}
```

Your URI is http://localhost:8080/app/products

Products is List of Product and you are trying to send only **Product** Object,Instead of sending **products** you have to pass List of Product.
So your post request should be like below:

```
{
 "products": [{
    "name": "MySmartPhone",
    "brand": "Samsung"
  }, {
    "name": "MySmartPhone1",
    "brand": "Nokia"
  }]
}
```